# break-word does not work inside table.td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I expect something like this:

```
|-----------panel-heading---------------------|
|    | Name           | Sex     |             |
|  wrap-word          |  wrap-word            |  
|               wrap-word                     |
```

but as you can see, the long word `111...` and `222...` does not wrap and the table is longer than panel

How to fix it?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">test </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr> 
        </thead>  
        <tbody>     
          <tr >   
            <td>ff</td>
            <td>wer</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
          </tr>     
          <tr class="">
            <td colspan="4">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">                    <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">                    <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</h2>
                    <hr>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">                  <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the words (long strings) break with `word-break: break-word;` in addition to your `word-wrap` like this:

```css
h2 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">test </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr> 
        </thead>  
        <tbody>     
          <tr >   
            <td>ff</td>
            <td>wer</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
          </tr>     
          <tr class="">
            <td colspan="4">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><h2>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><h2>22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</h2>
                    <hr>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><h2>33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will also work on other elements like `divs`, `spans` etc.

What's the difference between `word-wrap` and `word-break`?

**word-wrap**: The word-wrap CSS property is used to specify whether or not the browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing box.

**word-break**: The word-break CSS property is used to specify how (or if) to break lines within words

In conclusion you need them both to break long strings without any spaces where the `word-wrap` could take in place.

Comment: Thanks, what's different between  word-wrap: break-word; and
  word-break: break-word; ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout:fixed` this will wrap the table within the width of the parent div and text will break automatically.

```css
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">test </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr> 
            </thead>  
            <tbody>     
              <tr >   
                <td>ff</td>
                <td>wer</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>asdf</td>
              </tr>     
              <tr class="">
                <td colspan="4">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">                    <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">                    <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</h2>
                        <hr>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">                  <h2 style="word-wrap: break-word">33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```